# no matching manifest for linux/386 in the manifest list entries

Tags: docker, docker-compose, x86, 32bit-64bit

Is there a way to work around this error:

> no matching manifest for linux/386 in the manifest list entries

While running:

```
> sudo docker-compose build
```

I know the error means this docker image doesn‘t support i386 architecture. But I have to use a 32-bit machine. Is this error a dead end? Is there anything I can do?

Comment: any solution you got?

Comment: @Kerem Yes, I switched to a 64-bit server :)